Why was a question about processor support for .NET AOT closed?
I asked if .NET AOT compilation was supported on ARM processors. The question was closed as seeking recommendations for off-site resources.
Is .NET AOT compilation supported on 64-bit ARM processors?
My confusion comes from the fact that similar questions such as the following are not closed:
.NET development for microprocessors
Does .NET 4.5.1 work on a Core 2 Duo processor?
.NET Framework support for multicore hardware
My question is not asking for off-site evidence; it's specifically asking if .NET AOT works on ARM.
Should I be doing something differently to avoid this issue?

Presumably because the closers felt requesting links to 3rd party resources showing you what you are asking for fit the close reason. I don't think explicitly asking for "not" links really changes that, people aren't going to answer this without finding official sources... that said i'm not convinced that's a great reason to use this close reason

Using examples from 10-16 years ago doesn't really make for good examples; in the early days [so] was a very different place. Plus, we're human, stuff that should be closed sometimes isn't; that doesn't make it on topic.

"I should be able to ask because someone else's similar question wasn't closed" is akin to someone asking their mom, "I should be able to do this because Johnny's mom let's him do it". My mom never accepted this logic and neither should the site since each question should stand or fall on its own merits.

To be frank your question showed zero research. Three comments all pointing out it supported both ARM and x86 and just having basic information about Visual Studio would allow you to know you can target both x86 and ARM.

While your question appears to lack research effort, lack of research is a downvote reason, not a close vote reason. Questions asking for the official support status of some hardware for a given programming language are on-topic, just like questions asking for the official location of some resource are on-topic.
The 'off-site resource recommendation' close reason is for questions where you're asking for someone to recommend a resource of their choice, not for questions asking "where is this official content located?" Thus I've voted to reopen your question, though I don't expect it will return to a positive score, given the aforementioned lack of research.
